# Edit the Publish Widget Options

Tags: php, customization, widgets, publish

Another noob question - under the 'Publish' widget in a default vanilla installation of WordPress 3.3.1, we would like to 'simplify' the Publish widget/

Specifically, we would like to have no 'draft' or 'Pending Review' functionality. Immediately, when the user clicks publish, the post is published.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `post_submitbox_misc_actions`

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'publish_in_frontpage' );
function publish_in_frontpage($post)
{
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_publish_in_frontpage', true);
    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last">
         <span id="timestamp">'
         . '<label><input type="checkbox"' . (!empty($value) ? ' checked="checked" ' : null) . 'value="1" name="publish_in_frontpage" /> Publish to frontpage</label>'
    .'</span></div>';
}
```